# Delete user from database when user not sharing any guilds with a bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to delete user from my mongo database in "guildMemberRemove" event if he is not sharing any guilds with my bot.

I'm creating new users in "guildMemberAdd" even if user doesn't exist in database.

So far I got this:

```js
bot.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => {
   const userGuilds = bot.guilds.map(g=> g.members.get(member.id)).filter(g => g);

   if (!userGuilds[0]) db.deleteUser(member.id); // function which deletes user from db
});
```

But I have been told what it won't work properly because of cache.

I don't want to accidentally remove all user data by accident. So please tell me a way to do it and be sure that the user is not sharing any guilds with a bot; even if it's a slow method.

Comment: Please use this query 
 db.deleteUser(ObjectId(member.id))

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar I just typed it as example it not a query im actually using. Not solving my question as well

Comment: Try using the `Guild#member()` method. `bot.guilds.every(guild => guild.member(member.id));`

Comment: @Steamgamer whats a difference? won't I have same caching problem?

Comment: The `members` property holds all cached `GuildMember`s, whereas `Guild#member()` fetches despite not being cached.